# adding {% trans " " %} tag inside {% if .....%} tag

Tags: python, django, internationalization

Base template that I have:

```
{% load auth_extras %}
{% if request.user|has_group:"Administrator" %}
<li><a href="/admin/"> Admin Section &nbsp;</a></li>
{% endif %}
{% if request.user|has_group:"Moderator" %}
<li><a href="/admin/">Admin Section </a></li>
{% endif %}
```

How to add {% trans " " %} tag to "Admin Section" in this case ??? Adding it dirrectly is restricted because I have tag in tag which is not allowed. Or will be better to ask - how to be in this case ?

Comment: This is perfectly ok to do `{% if request.user|has_group:"Moderator" %}
<li><a href="/admin/">{% trans "Admin Section" %}</a></li>
{% endif %}`. What your issue is here?

Comment: local server fails if {% trans " " %} is inside if tag (

Answer (score 2):

can you use `trans ... as`? more details [trans-template-tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#trans-template-tag)

```
{% trans "Admin Section" as adm_section %}
{% if request.user|has_group:"Moderator" %}
<li><a href="/admin/"> {{ adm_section }}</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: glad to help you)

Comment: Alternatively you can use `{% blocktrans %}`, (Documentation)[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#std:templatetag-blocktrans]